# Many-To-Many + WHERE field <> value

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I have "Post" entity with relation manyToMany

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Core\CoreBundle\Entity\User", cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="blogregion_post_views")
 */
protected $views;

 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application\BlogRegionBundle\Entity\PostTag", cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="blogregion_tags_match")
 */
protected $tags;
```

And i want to get a new Posts

```
    $query = $this->getEm()->createQuery("
        SELECT p FROM BlogRegionBundle:Post p LEFT JOIN p.tags t LEFT JOIN p.views v
        WHERE t.id = :blogId AND p.state = :state AND p.deleted = 0 AND (v <> :user OR v IS NULL )

    ")
        ->setParameter('blogId', $blogId)
        ->setParameter('state', 1)
        ->setParameter('user', $this->getUser())
    ;
```

but it return "Post" if my user exist in "views" relation

How i can resolve this problem?

Comment: Could you explain what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I`m try to get a new Posts for current users. The table "p.views" contains all users, which read a post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a `MEMBER OF` condition.

```
SELECT p FROM BlogRegionBundle:Post p LEFT JOIN p.tags t WHERE t.id = :blogId AND p.state = :state AND p.deleted = 0 AND :user NOT MEMBER OF p.views
```

From http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-examples

Comment: Thanks! It`s work!
ooorhh.. Mysql have a much powerfull function.

Comment: As far as I know 'MEMBER OF' is not a MySQL construct. Doctrine will translate it into some kind of nested select/join. Though I agree it is a cool construct..